# How to use all variable names in variable list inside proc freq

Tags: sas, frequency

I am trying to use all variable names in the variable list (varlistc) inside proc freq. However, PROC FREQ only provided output for the last variable name in varlistc. How can I fix this?

```
proc sql noprint;
select name 
into :varlistc separated by ' '
from data2c;
quit;

proc freq data=&data1;
table &varlistc*site;
run;
```

Answer (score 4):

Just for the reference, PROC FREQ also allows for a clearer syntax:

every variable from list in first brackets cross-applied to the variable (or list of variables in another brackets) after asterix.

```
proc sql noprint;
select name
into :varlistc separated by ' '
from sashelp.class;
quit;


proc freq data=&data1;
table ( &varlistc ) * site;
run;
```

Could be also e.g.:

```
proc freq data=&data1;
table ( &varlistc ) * (site1 site2);
run;
```

Comment: Interesting, never realized that!

Comment: Hi, the macro variable is just displaying one variable not all. I am using the following code.

Comment: proc sql noprint;
  select name into :varlist
  from dictionary.columns
  where memname = 'RD_1174';
quit;
proc freq data=prof.rd_1174 ORDER=freq;
table &varlist;
run;

Answer (score 1):

Add more into your macro variable to get this to work properly.

```
proc sql noprint;
select cats(name,'*site')
into :varlistc separated by ' '
from data2c;
quit;

proc freq data=&data1;
table &varlistc;
run;
```

This will generate all of the tables on the screen. If you are looking to output them to a dataset, if you add a `/out` that will not output except the last table; you have two options.

- Use `ods output` to get all of the output into one or more datasets
- Include `/out=<whatever>` in your `select into`.